# Running all instances of inherited classes with one method

Tags: python, parsing, inheritance, aiohttp

I'm trying to build an asyncronous parser. I'm a novice in both OOP and asyncronous programming.

I have 3 main resources from which I'm parsing data. Within each resource I have several web pages to parse from, ranging from 3 to 30 pages. I would like to keep a persistent ClientSession() for each of the 3 main resources due to authorization procedures.

I'm creating a main Parser class, three subclasses, and more 'sub-subclasses' which inherit from the three subclasses. The idea is that I run a single Parser.run() method, and all three resources get parsed automatically, returning one json object.

I need it in a class, because I'm planning to scale it so that I run many instances of the parent Parser class, each will have it's own authorization data and I'd like them all to run asynchronously.
For now I have three main questions:

1. How do I initialize all my child class instances, each with different url to parse, so that I can later run them all with one method?
2. I need to keep a persistent ClientSession() for each resource, am I doing it correctly?
3. How do I then return a json object (a dict) from each resource and access them all from the Parser() instance?

I would be grateful for any directions or links.

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import Semaphore
from datetime import datetime
import random

from aiohttp import ClientSession


class Parser:
    # several user agents to randomly sample from
    user_agents = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 YaBrowser/17.6.1.749 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 YaBrowser/18.3.1.1232 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 YaBrowser/17.4.3.195.10 Mobile/14A346 Safari/E7FBAF',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36']

    def __init__(self):
        self.url = None
        self.headers = {}
        self.user_agent = random.choice(Parser.user_agents)
        self.parsers = [] # keep three SupParsers (Api1Parser, Api2Parser, Api3Parser)
        self.response = None # keep response for logging purposes

    async def parse(self, session: ClientSession): # empty method for inheritance
        pass

    def log(self):
        print(datetime.now(), flush=True)
        print(self.url, flush=True)
        print(self.response.status_code, flush=True)

    def add_parser(self, parser: 'Parser'):
        self.parsers.append(parser)

    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        futures = []
        for parser in self.parsers:
            futures.append(asyncio.create_task(parser.gather_tasks()))
        all_futures = asyncio.gather(*futures)
        loop.run_until_complete(all_futures)


class Api1Parser(Parser):

    semaphore = Semaphore(value=100) # limit total connections across each ClientSession()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.headers['User-Agent'] = self.user_agent
        self.jobs = []
        self.tasks = []
        self.json_ = {}
        super().add_parser(self)

    def add_job(self, job: 'Parser'):
        self.jobs.append(job)

    async def gather_tasks(self):
        async with ClientSession(headers=self.headers) as session:
            for job in self.jobs:
                task = asyncio.create_task(job.parse(session))
                self.tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*self.tasks)


class Page1Api1Parser(Api1Parser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.url = 'https://someApiService.domain'
        super().add_job(self)

    async def parse(self, session: ClientSession):
        async with ApiParser.semaphore:
            async with session.get(self.url) as resp:
                self.response = resp
                json_ = await resp.read()
                super().json_['Page1'] = json_


parser = Parser()
parser.run()
```